# Duplicate local variables

Tags: java

The error says `Duplicate local variables Months, Weeks, Salary`. This is my code:

```
    int Months, Weeks, Days, Salary;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number of days: ");
    Days=keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Working period is "+Days+" days");

    double Months;
    Months = Days/30;
    Days  = Days%30;
    System.out.println("Months : "+ Months);

    double Weeks;
    Weeks = Days/30;
    Days = Days%7;
    System.out.println("Weeks : "+ Weeks);
    System.out.println("Days : "+ Days);

    double Salary;
    Salary = Months*3500+Weeks*850+Days*85;
    System.out.println("Total Payment : "+Salary+" TL.");

}
```

I don't understand I get such an error.

Comment: You are declaring months, weeks and salary 2 times, first as int, then as double.

Comment: By deleting the declarations that you don't need

Comment: Just remove months , week and salary from int declaration.

Comment: Your question title should be about your **question**, not your level of experience.

Comment: please check one of the answer you found useful~

Answer (score 1):

You are defining Months, Weeks and Salary twice; initially as int in the starting and then as double.
Just
 remove months , week and salary from int declaration safely.

Answer (score 1):

Remove following variables which are repetition in your code...

```
double Months;
double Weeks;
int Salary;
```

Answer (score 1):

What `datatype` you want to use ? `int` or `double` ?

You have defined  `int` Months, Weeks, Days, Salary at first, but then you defined them as `double` again. Just remove one of the datatype follow by its variable and it should fine.

Answer (score 1):

To fix it you can also rename:

```
double Months;
double Weeks;
double Salary;
```

to

```
double monthsDbl;
double weeksDbl;
double SalaryDbl;
```

and use correct names